# Read jpg from file and upload/post to webserver in android

Tags: android, http

I've reviewed and several related questions (for example this code is posted alot but doesn't work for me for some reason: [How do I add REQUEST values to an HTTP POST method using multipart to upload a file to a PHP server in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613088/how-do-i-add-request-values-to-an-http-post-method-using-multipart-to-upload-a-f)) and attempted a couple solutions but my file when viewed on the server is not decodeable as a jpg.  I have the upload working in a iPhone app but now when I'm porting to android I can't figure out the right way to do this.  The server side is an asp.net streaming file upload api.

Here is my base64 encode logic:

```
Bitmap fileToUpload = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(obs.getPhotoLocation());    
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fileToUpload.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();                        
String data = Base64.encodeToString(image, true);
new HttpConnection(handler).postBitmap(url.toString(), data);
```

Here is the postBitmap code

```
HttpPost httpPostBitmap = new HttpPost(url);
httpPostBitmap.addHeader("Content-type", "image/jpg");
httpPostBitmap.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
httpPostBitmap.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));
response = httpClient.execute(httpPostBitmap);
```

The file before transfer and on the server are the same sizes so I don't believe it is a problem with the transfer and more likely a problem with the encoding.

Here is the working iOS code I'm attempting to port:

```
NSURL *uploadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:FILEUPLOAD_URL];
UIImage *testImage = [Helpers getImageFromPhoto:self.obsToTransmit.observationPhoto];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(testImage, 1.0);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [imageData length]];
[request addValue:@"image/jpg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:imageData];

theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Thanks a bunch!
Scott

Comment: Found the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363577/streaming-file-from-android-to-net-http-service.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Base64 to encode the image to String and on the other end at Server, change the String of Base64 to Image by decoding it. Check the link [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html which is supported from 2.2. We also have Base64.java available for less than 2.2 version devices.